# monitoring packets in promiscuous mode using ns2

Tags: c++, c, ns2

my current project is about capturing the packets in promiscuous mode  and simulating it using ns2.Hence I have implemented a simple program containing 3 nodes where sender 'a' sending tcp packets to destination 'b' and udp packets to destination 'c'. I have executed a c++ program where it captures the packet in promiscuous mode.My question is how do i include that .cc executable file in my tcl program on node 'a'. Is there any way to do this ? please do anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: You should improve the quality of your question if you want to have any answer. [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot include your .cc directly with tcl instead of that you have to add your code with available *.cc code. for example the Promiscuous operations already available in dsr.cc so you can put your new code in dsr.cc and use "make" to compile your ns2. now from your tcl script you can call DSR as a routing protocol.